# Can't Install Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK

Tags: sdk, lync

I am trying to install the Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK and when I run the installer I get the below warning.  I've installed the Microsoft C++ redistributable, which is version 11.0.6 something and it still doesn't work...any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit one?

Comment: I did - Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.60610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft apparently requires the *exact version* of the runtime specified in the error message.  It is available on the Lync Server 2013 ISO Image (DVD).

http://lyncuc.blogspot.com/2013/07/installing-lync-server-2013-debugging.html

Comment: Funnily, merely the Lync redist assemblies + VS 2010 Express turn to be enough to start with Lync dev-t :)